# SVN: how to move the contents of a folder into another folder

Tags: svn, copy, move

How do I move the contents (files) inside one folder (A) into another folder (B) without copying over (B)'s current contents?

```
Folder A
 - file 1
 - file 2
 - file 3

Folder B
 - file 4
 - file 5
 - file 6
```

I'd like the end result to be:

```
Folder A
 - empty

Folder B
 - file 1
 - file 2
 - file 3
 - file 4
 - file 5
 - file 6
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
svn move foldera/file*.ext folderb
svn commit -m "move all files in foldera to folderb" .
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html

If you have files with the same filename in the target directory they will be overwritten.  You'll have to inspect and issue the correct svn move command (or multiples of it) for your situation.  This works in your local directory so you can inspect the results before you check in.  If you use the svn url instead of paths in your working copy it'll be committed immediately.

Comment: I just did it on my box.  I would paste the output but it doesn't remain formatted in the comments.  svn 1.6.5 on a mac.